# Emacs can't find package to install

Tags: emacs, projectile, melpa

I got this error when trying install Emacs package automatically.

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/Users/username/.emacs.d/init.el':

File error: http://melpa.org/packages/projectile-20150619.800.el, Not found

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

Comment: Can you connect to melpa in a browser?

Comment: Yes, Emacs cannot find that package. *What's the question?*

Answer (score 8):

You need to first refresh ELPA package archives by <kbd>M-x package-refresh-contents</kbd>, because yours are out-of-date so the package manager can't download package for you.

You can also install packages from [Package Menu](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Menu.html) (entering via <kbd>M-x list-packages</kbd>), refreshing will be done automatically.

Answer (score 5):

And here's my solution:

- Open your browser, and enter: http://melpa.org/
- Search package name: 'projectile'
- Then download and extract the package into ~/.emacs.d/elpa

Answer (score 1):

If you use ubuntu you can also just use `apt-get install elpa-projectile` as described in [documentation](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile).

Answer (score 0):

One reason this may be happening is that you may be trying to set up the package in your emacs.el file before setting up the melpa connection, so your package list is much smaller. Try disabling it there and refreshing the package list to see if that helps.